# cognito forget password flow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have to implement forget password in my application, first I used this code and get the OTP successfully on email.

```
this.cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
  onSuccess: function (data) {
    // successfully initiated reset password request
     console.log('CodeDeliveryData from forgotPassword: ' + data);
  },
  onFailure: function (err) {
  }
});
```

Now on the second page, I have to verify the OTP and then on the third page, I have to ask for new password. 
According to the docs here on callback, I have to give both otp and new password. Suggest me please how can I divide it into three steps??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on the Cognito team and this is not possible at this point since as you noted, both the OTP and the new password are passed in the same call.

Comment: Is my answer incorrect? I have working code that handles forgotten passwords.

Comment: yes but he wants to confirm the code first and after that set the password. currently, we only allow to submit both of them at the same time, not separately

Comment: @IonutTrestian Thank you

Comment: @IonutTrestian when are you going to support above use case?

Answer (score 1):

After calling forgotPassword(), the user received a code. Call confirmForgotPassword() with the code, new password and user name. The last step is to log the user in by calling initiateAuth() or adminInitiateAuth().

Comment: On the second page I want to verify code with the user name, than on third page I want to enter new password

Answer (score 0):

Create a Lambda function to store OTP agains user email in DB.

Attach this Lambda to forget password flow in cognito. See details on below link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html

Then create a API for OTP verification, and then use this API in step 2, and on step 3 pass OTP and password in single flow